# how to control which parts the && applies to in an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

let say I have this if statement:

```
if($(this).hasClass('rightnav') | $(this).parent() == 'nav' && $(this).parent().parent() == 'section')
```

How can I tell the script that the && should apply after the | and not the entire if?
Thanks! this is really confusing me :s

Comment: Consider `$(this).parent().is('nav')`, because the equality operation that you're doing doesn't work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(($(this).hasClass('rightnav') | $(this).parent() == 'nav') && $(this).parent().parent() == 'section')
```

and shouldn't it be `||` instead of `|` ?

Answer (score 4):

Note that you should have `||` (logical-or) instead of `|` (bitwise-or).

Second, logical-and (`&&`) has higher precedence than logical-or (`||`).  See numbers 13 and 14 in the list of precedence here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/operator_precedence

But if you're not sure, or to help out maintenance coders who come along later, parentheses are a good choice.  Whatever is in the parens will get executed first.

I think this should do it:

`if(($(this).hasClass('rightnav') || $(this).parent() == 'nav') && $(this).parent().parent() == 'section')`

Comment: what is the precise difference between | and ||?

Comment: Logical-or works the way you think.  Bitwise-or  works on bits, so if `a=1100` and `b=0110`, then `a|b` returns `1110`.  For each bit position, if either `a` or `b` has a 1 in that position, then the result has a 1 there.  Otherwise the result has a 0.  See example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LUgwN/